# How to restrict paste values in form?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that contains a phone number field

```
<input name="phNumber" type="text" class="numbersonly"/>
```

using js i can allow only number but,i wanna to restrick paste value from mouse...

{NOTE: No Validation is required in this field}

Comment: *"i wanna to restrick paste value from mouse"* Why? Why not let your user do what suits *them*?

Comment: If it's not validated, why does pasting matter?

Comment: i wanna store phone in database and retrieve in view side,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind an event to your input component:

```
$('selector').bind('paste', function() {
  return false;
});
```

See for reference: [jQuery API - bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: This just binds a function (that does nothing) to a component that reacts on a specific event. I don't see anything complicated.

Comment: No seriously. What is complicated for you? - May I can explain better.

Comment: thnk i thing u r corrrect palll

Answer (score 1):

You can respond to the `change` event, removing any non-digits.

```
$("input.numbersonly").change(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
});
```

That uses a regular expression (`/\D/g`) to match all non-digits and replace them with the replacement string (in this case, nothing — `""`). The `\D` part is the "non-digit" part, and the `g` is the flag meaning "global" (throughout the string).

---

**Off-topic**: I really, really wouldn't disallow all non-digits in a phone number field. People are used to writing phone numbers with spaces, hyphens, perhaps parentheses, maybe even the plus sign (e.g., `+1 (408) 123-4567`). Phone numbers can be very difficult to read (and therefore to type correctly) if you remove these cues. You do want your users to type the number correctly, right? In which case, I would keep the validation pretty open.

Comment: @Karth: Sorry, I did mean to explain the regexp. Done now.

Comment: ya i got pal<input name="phNumber" type="text" onpaste="return false" class="numbersonly"/><br/>